# How to use debug version of a shared object

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have to use a debug version of a shared library (in particular libpcap installed in Ubuntu via `apt-get install libpcap0.8-dbg`)...i build my executable and link against it and all works (verified with `ldd`)...but when i run the executable i get a segfault...the dynamic linker can't load the library. Using `objdump` i see that `Dynamic section` is empty:

```
$objdump -p libpcap.so.1.1.1
...
Dynamic section:

$
```

I think that in ELF shared objects some fields of `Dynamic section` are mandatory...so, why this section is empty? Maybe there is a different method for loading it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I don't use Ubuntu, but AFAIK debug packages do not contain full versions of libraries or binaries, just stripped debugging informations from them.  These are just sections cut out by eu-strip or similar tool.  You should not link against them.  As matter of fact, there's no need to relink your app at all.  You should just instruct gdb, valgrind or other debugging information consumer to read them before actual debugging if the tools are not able to do that by themselves, that's all.

Comment: The debug version of the library has also full .text, .data, etc...sections, not only debug ones so i think that it's the same of the non-debug version but compiled with debug syms.

Comment: You may want to check out this bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=462456

Answer (score 0):

You could try running with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/debug/`

Comment: The problem is not about dynamic linker that doesn't find the library...it segfaults when loads it (i verified with LD_DEBUG=all env variable). I tried also LD_PRELOAD but the results are the same.

Comment: Then uninstall & reinstall `libpcap0.8-dbg` or maybe compile with `CFLAGS=-g` the upstream `libpcap`